Reading $B^{-1}$ from simplex table
In uni I'm following a course on optimalisation and I have come across a problem. I am given the following minimalisation problem:

and the corresponding final Simplex table:

I now need to determine the $B^{-1}$ matrix corresponding to this table. The problem is that the first restriction is an equality restriction, so we don't have an identity matrix in the initial table, and thus we cant just read it off from the columns of the slack variables.
An idea I had was to read $B$ from columns $a_2, a_3, a_4$ from the original matrix (because we see an identity matrix in the final table) and then just calculate the inverse by hand, does that give the desired result?
Thanks in advance!!
